# Excel: How to calculate sum of non empty cells in column, based on value in another column?

Tags: excel

I need help with a formula for excel to calculate the number of cells in a column where the cell is not empty, but where the value of a cell in another column equals a certain value.

Example excel layout:

```
1| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4
--------------------------------------------
2|   R5     |    x     |          |    x
3|   R4     |    x     |     x    |    x
4|   R4     |    x     |     x    |    x
5|   R2     |    x     |          |
6|   R3     |    x     |     x    |    x
7|   R1     |    x     |          |    x
8|   R4     |    x     |     x    |
9|   R2     |    x     |     x    |
```

How do I calculate the number of cells in column 3 that have an x if, and only if, the cell value in column1 is R3?

Manual calculation says that the sum would be 1. It would be 3 if the condition for column1 were R4.

I have been using the following formula for calculating the sum of columns(named) that meet a certain condition.

`=SUM(--(MMULT(--(ranks="R5"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(ranks)))>0))`

I have tried to use the above formula in conjunction with the AND function to do what I need to do, but I cannot make it work.

Comment: Countifs should do what you require: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,"R5",C2:C9,"?*")`